# Fixed cross reference layout "Only label and number"

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2013, cross-reference

I always want a e.g. figure cross reference to show only label and number. Is there a way to default to this setting instead of having to select this from the corresponding dialog each time I re-open a document?  Or at least make the dialog point to this option by default?

Maybe, there is a way to use VBA or some scripting to fix this. However, as I see it, these 4 options have little correlated field codes. In a sample document & a sample picture, I get the following results:

```
Entire caption              REF _Ref379450337 \h
Only label and number       REF _Ref379442039 \h 
Only caption text           REF _Ref379451322 \h
Page number                 PAGEREF _Ref379450337 \h
Above/below                 REF _Ref379450337 \p \h
```

Hence, once I have the field code for an entire caption, I can change this to the page number or above / below layout. What I need is something that tells me, whether this is **not** "Only label and number" and then changes the field code accordingly.

I also appreciate information on why this is not possible (if so).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was annoyed by the same thing, and even more by the fixed mini size of the dialog (shame on the responsible designer!). So I wrote a macro to insert cross references more comfortably. It works as follows (after you have assigned a hotkey to it):

1. Position the cursor to where the crossref should be inserted
2. Press the hotkey => a temporary bookmark is inserted (grey square brackets if you have configured them to be shown)
3. Navigate to the element to which the crossref is to be inserted, e.g. a figure label or a headline. I find it especially comfortable to use the navigation pane / Headlines to quickly navigate to the destination.
4. Press the hotkey again. The cursor jumps back to the original location and inserts the crossreference there.

You may access it on [GitHub](https://github.com/Traveler4/InsertCrossReferencesComfortably).